# PHRETS Error Message: Missing operator in lookup subquery

Tags: php, rets, phrets, idx, dmql

I am learning to use PHRETS to access IDX data for a real estate website. I have managed to connect and do simply queries using limits on price, character field content, etc. but I am getting an error message when I try to limit results by the listing status field.

According to RETS-MD the SystemName for the field is "Property_Status", the field type is "Character", the length is 2 and one of the potential Values is "A" (as well as others).

When I run the following code I get an error message that says "Fatal error:  Uncaught PHRETS\Exceptions\RETSException: Missing operator in lookup subquery for field Property_Status. in C:\xampp\phrets\vendor\troydavisson\phrets\src\Session.php:424"

```
$results = $rets->Search('Property','RESD','(List_Price=100000-105000),(Property_Status=A)');
```

I have also tried searching for "A*" and "*A*", same result. The strange thing is that I can do a search on other character fields which don't contain a preset list of potential values without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the mentioned field "Property_Status" is a look-up field. And the syntax for including a look-up field should prefix "|" pipe symbol along with the value.

Your query should be,

```
$rets->Search('Property','RESD','(List_Price=100000-105000),(Property_Status=|A)');
```

If suppose multiple status needs to query then,

```
$rets->Search('Property','RESD','(List_Price=100000-105000),(Property_Status=|A,B)');
```